# JS Remove Every Other Element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, nodes

I tried this code to remove every other element in the body, but it didn't work.

```js
s = document.body.childNodes;
for (var i = 1; i < (s.length / 2); i++) {
  if ((i % 2) == 0) {
    document.body.removeChild(s[1]);
  } else {
    document.body.removeChild(s[0]);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <div id="div2"></div>
  <div id="div3"></div>
  <div id="div4"></div>
  <div id="div5"></div>
  <div id="div6"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: try `document.body.removeChild(s[i])` instead of `removeChild(s[1])`. And to remove "every other element in body", you could [`cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode) the element you want before settings body's `innerHTML` to '' and then append the cloned node

Comment: why are you trying to remove with both conditions? logic doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get the elements using `children` or `querySelectorAll()` not `childNodes`, `childNodes` will get all nodes including the text. Try the following code:

```
var s = document.body.children;
var itemCount = s.length;

for (var i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
{
   if (i % 2 !== 0)
   {
     document.body.removeChild(s[i]);
   }
}
```

Here is a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/majilibigelu/3/edit) example.

Note that in JSBin we get the elements using `querySelectorAll()`, beacuse it also adds script elemets inside the body, for example:

```
var s = document.querySelectorAll('div');
```

Also, note that IE8 and below includes comment nodes when using `children`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with your code. For one thing the logic is off, but there are some major problems with how the code deals with the DOM manipulations:

1. Your HTML causes text nodes to be created between your elements. And your code does not handle this.
2. The `childNodes` list changes as you remove nodes from the parent element.

With this HTML:

```
<div id="test-container">
    <div id="div1">1</div>
    <div id="div2">2</div>
    <div id="div3">3</div>
    <div id="div4">4</div>
    <div id="div5">5</div>
    <div id="div6">6</div>
</div>
```

And this JavaScript:

```
var container = document.getElementById("test-container");
var child = container.firstElementChild;
var remove = true;
while (child) {
    var next = child.nextElementSibling;
    if (remove)
        container.removeChild(child);
    remove = !remove;
    child = next;
}
```

I can remove every other child. I avoid both problems I pointed out earlier by using `firstElementChild` and `nextElementSibling`.

Comment: This answers the question, but its first supported from IE9 and up.

Comment: @null Project requirements will vary of course, but IMO targeting IE9+ is reasonable. IE9 is two versions behind now, even Google only supports the [two most recent versions](http://googleforwork.blogspot.com/2011/06/our-plans-to-support-modern-browsers.html) of a browser.

Comment: @UselessCode Its worth noticing that Google are only aiming to target 2 version back when talking about google apps. Not their main page.

Comment: @NULL Yeah, search doesn't really need any of the newer browser features to do it's job but GMail, Docs, etc are still major products that a large part of their user-base uses. It was a big deal when they made that decision for those products.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know that a nodeList will update when the dom is updated, that means that if you are removing the first child node, the element 0 in the list will not refer to `null` but the node that was initial child 1.

This means that if you want to remove node 0, 2, 4, 6, ... you will actually have to remove 0,1,2,3,4... (because the nodeList always will update):

```
var body = document.body;
// Consider that you might want to use `body.children` instead of 
// `body.childNodes` because it excludes all text nodes 
var nodes = body.childNodes; 
var len = nodes.length / 2;

for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
    body.removeChild(nodes[i]);
}
```

I know it can seams kind of odd, but this will actually remove all the nodes: 0, 2, 4, 6, ...

[image: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.children]

[See more at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.children)

Comment: Using this code with `body.childNodes` will remove all the text nodes, but leave the elements alone, due to the way the parent element is structured (text node, element, text node, element, etc.) Yes, I saw the comment but this is a pretty *big* caveat. If `children` is used, then you might want to point out that `children` is supported from IE 9 and up since you commented on my answer that `firstElementChild` and co are supported only from IE 9 and up.

Comment: @Louis `.children` is supported from IE6 and up with the quirk that it will include comments as nodes. eg `[<div>, <!-- -->, <p>, ..]` while newer browsers (IE9 and up) exclude the comment tags: `[<div>, <p>, ..]`

Comment: Ok, so the correct way to put it is that IE < 9 does not support `children` *per the spec*, then.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors) with a [`:nth-child(odd)`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#structural-pseudos) selector:

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('body > div:nth-child(odd)');
divs = [].slice.call(divs); // convert from NodeList to real array

divs.forEach(function(elem) {
  document.body.removeChild(elem);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UselessCode/j2eksc58/)

Answer (score -1):

Why not use jQuery and simply do:

```
$('.remOdd').on('click', function(){
  $('div').filter(':odd').remove();
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dh5uymzL/

Or of course use ":even" if you like

http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: There is no jquery involved here. Why bring a library in for something that css can take care of natively?